# Xamarin Forms - Charts Controls and Web View

Tags: xamarin, charts, xamarin.forms

Recently I've been working on a project where we are required to build some mobile apps. Due to the cross platform needs the company decided to go for Xamarin Forms but we have been looking for charts controls and the only ones we've found that run across all platforms (android, iOS and UWP) are paid ones.

I won't go into details on why it can't be a paid solution but the thing is that since we are having a hard time to find free controls for our needs, someone suggested to implement a solution where we could have a open source chart library made in Javascript inside the mobile apps and load it using WebView controls and html files.

I'm fully aware that this "solution" has drawbacks such as performance and I can imagine that generating the html files needed and dynamically loading data into the charts won't be an easy task too.

Does someone out there have any experience with this kind of topics and can help us better understand which solutions we may have and what other drawbacks we have when using webviews?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: www.oxyplot.org

Comment: Hi @Jason thanks for the suggestion. We already saw that solution but the kind of graphics it generates are not really enough. As far as I'm aware we'll probably need bars, stacked bars, radars and pies.

Comment: AFAIK it can do all of those.

Comment: you're right @Jason . we initially didn't see all the available functionalities of oxyplot. Documentation is not great, but we were able to prove that it works. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oxyplot has proven its values. we decided to use that. Thanks for the tip Jason